# Semi-Eulerization Algorithm (for dummies)

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory, matching

I'm an engineer by training, not a CS person, so this question may come across as rather simplistic, but hopefully someone can give me some help.

I've got a graph that is non-Eulerian, but needs to be traced by an Eulerian path (not an Eulerian tour, hopefully). In order to semi-Eulerize it, I can only remove edges. What I want to figure out is how to do this with removing the fewest number of edges possible.

How would I construct an algorithm to do this? Ideally, a step-by-step description would be great. (remember: engineer, not CS person ... sorry)

Comment: Are you looking for an implementation in a programming language?  This doesn't sound like a programming question.

Comment: This sounds more like an attempt at getting help for a homework assignment in disguise. What specific requirement does this meet for an engineering purpose?

Comment: This seems tricky. The Chinese postman problem is the related problem of duplicating a subset of edges so that there's an Euler tour, but the T-join machinery doesn't apply cleanly because we now have to concern ourselves with disconnecting the graph.

Comment: FWIW, the directed version is NP-hard: http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0377-2217(91)90266-X

Comment: So is the problem of maximizing the number of vertices in the subgraph (claimed in http://arxiv.org/pdf/1304.5746v1.pdf by reference to H. Fleischner
,
Eulerian Graphs and Related Topics, Part 1, Volume
1
, Annals of Discrete Mathematics 45, Amsterdam, 1990.)

Comment: ...from which there is an easy reduction to the edge-maximizing version, making it (i.e., your problem) NP-hard. How large are your graphs? Do they have any special properties (e.g., planar)?

Comment: JAL, I'm more trying to understand the general theory of this, but I'll be implementing it in Matlab eventually. Ken White, this is for a modular robotics task in a research lab. I can't discuss the exact nature of the work, hence the vague language. @David Eisenstat I actually am less concerned about disconnecting the graph. If a few nodes get completely isolated from the graph, I'm ok with removing them entirely. That said, I want to minimize the number of edges removed, so hopefully not too many nodes will get eliminated.

Comment: What if we have two large components? Are we forced to delete one?

Comment: Valid point, from a CS perspective. I hadn't considered that because in real life, this is a 3D grid, and all the "problem nodes" that have odd order are on the outside surfaces of the 3D shape, so deleting edges from them wouldn't split the shape. That said, from the programming side I'm not sure if I have to deal with this. It may be enough in this case to overlook this issue, and just know that in this application it won't happen that way

Comment: I've been considering (and trying to implement) the strategy described in the answer to this question that I found since posted this one ... does this seem like the right direction? It adds elements instead of removing them, but I don't think that's a huge issue in my case.

http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/9126/is-there-a-non-brute-force-algorithm-for-eulerization-of-graphs